# post action insert and email form

Tags: php, post

I have a form on godaddy that I use to insert data into my database that has the following form action

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" style="color:#FFF;">
```

I have another form that allows users to send me email that looks like this:

```
<form name="mailform" id="mailform" method="POST" action="/webformmailer.php">
```

I want to be able to email the data that I am inserting into the database to myself, how would I add the post action="/webformmailer.php" action so that when a user hits the insert button on my insert.php, that I would also email me the data that is inserted into the database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should add the code of `webformmailer.php` into `insert.php`

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to call webformmailer.php from insert.php

Comment: The thing is, you can redirect to `webformmailer.php` after it has finished executing `insert.php`, but the `POST` values will be lost. Or you can do it this way, in your `webformmailer.php`, retrieve the records from the database and not from `POST`. Hope you get what I meant.

Comment: Why not making an include of the file webformmailer.php inside insert.php?

Comment: Yes that is true both ways would work, could select the data form the db and send it or I could use and include webformmailer in insert.

Comment: Would I just do an include(insert.php)?

Comment: Make the send email a helper function, include the file wherever you want to use it, and call the function.

Comment: I'm new to php, can you post an example of how to make it a helper function for including? Thanks

Comment: The include works great, thanks everyone for your posts!